# Java Aspect returned value to be used in the method

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an `@After` java aspect that runs certain logic. I need it to return a result (an object) that can be used in the methods intercepted by the aspect's pointcut. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `@Around` which allows you to return whatever you want to the advised object:

```
@Around("com.xyz.myapp.UserService.createUser()")
public Object userCreationAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    //Do something if needed before method execution
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
    //Do something if needed after method execution
    return retVal;
}
```